# `pkgdown`: use hexSticker package logo in navbar (instead of favicon)

Tags: html, css, r, navbar, pkgdown

In package `pkgdown`, is there any way to use a hexSticker package logo in the navbar, instead of a favicon logo?

Right now, a `_pkgdown.yml` file might contain the following code to link to another package:

```r
navbar:
  type: default
  toc: TRUE
  right:
  - text: rempsyc
    href: https://rempsyc.remi-theriault.com/
    aria-label: rempsyc
```

Using a favicon, we would replace `- text: rempsyc` with something like `- icon: fa-github` if we wanted the GitHub logo. I'm wondering if it would be possible instead to use something like:

`- icon: favicon\favicon-16x16.png` for using the current package logo in the navbar (stored in `pkgdown\favicon`). And possibly `- icon: assets\logo2.png` for using another package logo stored in `pkgdown\assets`. Is this possible?